# NLP verb to noun in Prolog

Tags: prolog, nlp, suffix

I'm trying to define a predicate `verb_to_noun(Av,N)`. That will take a verb 'celebrate' and change it to the noun 'celebration'. I'm struggling not only to add the suffix -tion, but also to delete the 'e' from the end of the verb. I've also defined the verb as verb(reg,celebrate). Any help or suggestions for how to start would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear by your question, but are you interested in other verbs as well besides "celebrate"? What class of nouns or verbs are you trying to change? Before writing any Prolog or even thinking about Prolog, you first need to determine what the "rule" is for conversion. If you can write out the rule (in plain language), then you can work the problem of converting that to Prolog. For example, a simplistic rule to pluralize might be "If word doesn't end in 's', then add 's', otherwise do nothing".

Answer (score 1):

With defintion

```
verb_to_noun(Av, N) :-
    verb(reg, Av),
    sub_atom(Av, Before, 2, 0, te),
    sub_atom(Av, 0, Before, 2, X),
    atom_concat(X, tion, N).
```

I get

```
?- verb_to_noun(celebrate, N).
N = celebration.
```

So you see how you can check end of atom or take part of atom and then make new atom from parts. All are predicates that are in SWI-Prolog and are marked with ISO so maybe they are in other implementations too?